# PySpark column is appending udf's argument value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have written a small program, it is working, but it is adding argument value into column which I do not need.

Input:

[image]

Expected:
Image above one upper into upper case

Getting:

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import logging
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit
from functools import partial

def main():
    process_function = {'TOLOWER' : process_lower_function }
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName('intelligent').getOrCreate()
    data = [(0, "cards"), (1, "upper")]
    deptColumns = ["index", "data"]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = deptColumns)
    print (df.show())
    process_rule = "pyspark,testing,upper"
    lower_function = partial(process_lower_function, process_rule)
    udf_parser = udf(lower_function)
    df = df.withColumn("ndata",udf_parser("data"))
    #df.write.csv("udf.csv")
    print (df.show())


def process_lower_function(text, lower_rule):
    print (lower_rule)
    for rule in lower_rule.split(","):
        if rule in text:
            text = text.replace(rule, rule.upper())
            logging.info(f"LOWER :: {text} -- {rule}")
    print (text)
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this definition...

```py
lower_function = partial(process_lower_function, process_rule)
```

... since you did not tell which `process_lower_function` function's argument should `process_rule` be used for, it is using the first one, i.e. `text`. But it seems you wanted `process_rule` to be used for the argument `lower_rule`. In this case you should use

```py
lower_function = partial(process_lower_function, lower_rule=process_rule)
```

Also, if you don't want a new column, replace the existent column's values. Instead of

```py
df = df.withColumn("ndata",udf_parser("data"))
```

use

```py
df = df.withColumn("data", udf_parser("data"))
```

The following seems to be working to me.

```py
import logging
from functools import partial
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def process_lower_function(text, lower_rule):
    print (lower_rule)
    for rule in lower_rule.split(","):
        if rule in text:
            text = text.replace(rule, rule.upper())
            logging.info(f"LOWER :: {text} -- {rule}")
    print(text)
    return text

data = [(0, "cards"), (1, "upper")]
deptColumns = ["index", "data"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=deptColumns)
df.show()
# +-----+-----+
# |index| data|
# +-----+-----+
# |    0|cards|
# |    1|upper|
# +-----+-----+

process_rule = "pyspark,testing,upper"
lower_function = partial(process_lower_function, lower_rule=process_rule)
udf_parser = F.udf(lower_function)
df = df.withColumn("data", udf_parser("data"))
df.show()
# +-----+-----+
# |index| data|
# +-----+-----+
# |    0|cards|
# |    1|UPPER|
# +-----+-----+
```

---

On the other hand, you should try to find better methods than `udf`. The best would be native Spark functions. If not that, then `pandas_udf` - it is vectorized for performance, while simple `udf` runs slowly.

I was not able to think of a native Spark solution, but the following `pandas_udf` should do what you want.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
import re

data = [(0, "cards"), (1, "uppers_testings")]
deptColumns = ["index", "data"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=deptColumns)
df.show()
# +-----+---------------+
# |index|           data|
# +-----+---------------+
# |    0|          cards|
# |    1|uppers_testings|
# +-----+---------------+
```

Script:

```py
@F.pandas_udf("string")
def to_upper(col: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    def repl(s):
        process_rule = "pyspark|testing|upper"
        return re.sub(fr'(.*?)({process_rule}|$)', lambda m: m.groups()[0] + m.groups()[1].upper(), s)
    return col.apply(repl)

df.withColumn("data", to_upper("data")).show()
# +-----+---------------+
# |index|           data|
# +-----+---------------+
# |    0|          cards|
# |    1|UPPERs_TESTINGs|
# +-----+---------------+
```